# Google maps api 2 doesnt show marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Google map doesn't show marker.
Here is my code snippet used for adding marker

```
googleMap = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

// check if map is created successfully or not
if (googleMap == null) {
  return ;
}

try {
  googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
} catch (Exception e) {
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Here is my xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Seems everything is fine with map and its showing in actual screen. Note that I am using this fragment inside the fragment (support lib) not extended from MapFragment.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Change your LatLng and set zoom on map to that place and see if is showing there... 
For example:

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(44.797283, 20.460663), 12))

map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(new LatLng(44.797283, 20.460663))
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
```

For more information: [How to add a marker on GoogeMapAPIv2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#add_a_marker)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
googleMap = ((MapFragment)getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
.getMap();
```

By this

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```